# Does anyone know from which book this excerpt comes from?

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally

Someone posted this excerpt on social media:

> Freedom in Judaism is defined by the ability of the soul to rule over
> the body, the capacity of the mind to channel the emotions of the
> heart. Not that the body and the heart are to be denigrated or
> ignored, rather they must be trained and channeled in the proper
> direction. Paradoxically, some people might feel that observing the
> Torah's precepts is the epitome of slavery because the individual must
> bend his or her will to follow an organized body of commandments that
> affect virtually every area of life. Yet those who choose to live by
> those laws quickly realize that by following the Torah, people free
> themselves from the tyrannical grasps of their lower instincts and
> baser desires, thus allowing themselves to develop their true essence
> and potential. From a Torah perspective, no amount of talent, power,
> and wealth can free a person, if he or she is still driven by baser
> desires. Torah is the instruction manual or road map leading us from
> slavery to ultimate freedom.

I've asked the OP where it comes from and even they themselves don't know. Does anyone here happen to know which book this is from, by any chance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Don’t know the book that that’s from, but I assume the source is the Mishnah in Avos chapter 6 Mishnah 2 that states “אין לך בן חורין אלא מי שעוסק בתלמוד תורה״. “There is no one who is considered free only one who toils in the learning of Torah.”

Comment: Definitely a C or other perspective and it's not Breslev I can tell you that. Because in the latter it's the the Heart that rules, not the Mind. See Sipure Maasiyot Tale 13 Seven Beggars - the Heart and the Spring.. every thing in the world has a heart, even a toenail has a heart and cannot survive without it.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I've just discovered that this excerpt is from the book The Story of Our Lives: An Epic Quest For The Soul of Our Tradition by R' Yaakov Klein.